# Mixed up default and named imports?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Working on displaying data in my Firebase Cloud Firestore, but I get an error when in my code. Can't understand what the issue is?

I have tried using export default in a new file, instead of using class for my RootStack, but I get an error when I try to do that as well.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Auth: {
      screen: Auth, navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login, navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Home: {
      screen: Home, navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
  }
);

   class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){

          super(props);
          this.state = ({
            todoTasks: []
          })
          this.ref = firestore.collection("tips");
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const todos = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            todos.push({
              tips: doc.data().tips
            })
          })
          this.setState({
            todoTask: todos
          })
        })
      }

    render() {
            return (
            <View>
                <Flatlist
                  data={this.state.todoTask}
                  renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    return(
                      <Text>{item.tips}</Text>)
                  }}
                  >
                  </Flatlist>
            </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: make sure `item.tips` is not undefined

Comment: @BinayakGhosh Isn’t it defined in querySnapshot?

Comment: Yes but you are pushing that in `componentDidMount()` which is called after `render()`. Try pushing that in the constructor itself.

Comment: @BinayakGhosh Tried that, but still doesn't work. Getting no error once I remove the Flatlist, I get no error.. If I move it out of both I get unexpected token.